# "Dogs are a type of animal"

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns

I have two questions.

(1) I know that we should say "Dogs are a type of animal". I wonder why we don't say "Dogs are a type of *an* animal"? For some reason, we have no article before *animal*. Is that just idiomatic?

(2) I'm confused as to when a noun is countable or not. For example, if you read the beginning of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_of_outcome) Wikipedia page:

> Equality of outcome, equality of condition, or equality of results is a political concept which is central to some political ideologies and is used regularly in political discourse, often in contrast to the term equality of opportunity.

I know that *outcome* could be a countable noun. For example, we say "these are two different outcomes." However, *equality of outcome* treats *outcome* as an uncountable noun (or a mass noun). Why can't we say, then, "equality of result"? "Outcomes" and "results" are essentially the same thing, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal not to use an article with "type of X". Saying "a dog is a type of animal" is equivalent to saying "a dog is an animal".

Yes, "result" would be better.
Also, since we are talking about something singular, which "is a political concept", the idea might better be put
"Equality of outcome (also called equality of condition or equality of result) is a political concept..."

Comment: How do I know that "result" can be an uncountable noun? By experience?

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily a question of countability as much as just whether to use a singular or plural noun. If you say, for example, there are no more inequities, you can say that is an outcome or a result (a countable use). You could use plural "outcomes" or "results" to refer to all the individuals that are being treated equally, but it isn't necessary to do that.

Comment: If "result" is countable, how can you say "equality of result", without any articles?

Comment: It's a question of a countable use. If you say "a result" referring to one of a set of several results, it's countable. If you say "of result", it's not countable.

Comment: Even though I am not the OP, I appreciate your answer.

Then, how about *Dogs are a type of animals*?

Comment: The usual way to say that is "a type of animal". When I see "a type of animals", I try to think what that could  add to the meaning, and I can't think what it might be.

Comment: Thank you. How did you know "result" could be uncountable? By experience?